# React dynamic Form inputs using antd

Tags: forms, next.js, nested, antd

I am trying to create dynamic form fields upon request in NextJs. The basic code so far looks like this:

```
return (
    <>
      <Row
        style={{
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <Col span={20}>
          <Form
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            autoComplete="off"
          >
            <Form.Item
              label="Title"
              name="title"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Title is required",
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input placeholder="Enter a title for the article" />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item
              label="Sub-Title"
              name="subTitle"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Sub Title is required",
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input placeholder="Enter a sub-title for the article " />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item
              label="Content"
              name="content1"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                },
              ]}
            >
              <TextArea rows={10} placeholder="Add Article Paragraph" />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
              <input type="file" name="file" multiple onChange={uploadImages} />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
```

[image]

I am using [AntD for UI designs](https://ant.design/). What I need to expand this functionality is to click on the 'Add more content' button, it should add more multiline input boxes and its name (or id) should become content2, content and so forth, so that the final structure of the single article JSON object should look like this:

```
{
    title: '',
    subTitle: '',
    content: [
      'content1': 'content one data',
      'content2': 'content two data'
    ]
}
```

I am aware that I can make use of React's useState() hook and define the object of form fields in that and push a new object every time upon button click but that pattern doesn't seem much valid to me as I am trying to utilise the Antd library itself.
If any leads in providing more better solution, will be really appreciated.

Comment: For 'content', You can use Form.List and Form.List provide `add` method to add more elements in a list. You can follow this [example](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item)

Comment: Well, I tried this example, but the example provided on official ANTD documentation doesn't have a default field opened. It creates a first input filed of the form only on the button click. I need to provide the first input field opened/existing and then append new fields (similar ones) if user clicks on button.

Comment: Connect your `<Form` component with `form` and then set default values after getting value from api.

Answer (score 0):

You can render `<Form.Item>` by a list such as:

```js
const FormConfig = [
  {
    label: "Title",
    name: "Title",
    ...
  },
  {
    label: "Content",
    name: "Content",
    components: [
      <TextArea rows={10} placeholder="Add Article Paragraph" />
    ]
  }
]
```

Each time you click the button, just push a new `<TextArea>` to components list.

Comment: Hi @J.chen Can you please help elaborate on the code sample, on how exactly you're suggesting to use the FormConfig? Thanks